# How to convert a DATE column to DATETIME in SQL, querying an Access database?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, datetime

I have a SQL query to where I need to convert a `DATE` column to `DATETIME` from an Access database.

The columns to be converted are:

```
CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
CHECKINOUT.DefaultIn
CHECKINOUT.DefaultOut
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT       
   USERINFO.NAME, USERINFO.EmployeeCode, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE,
   CHECKINOUT.DefaultIn, CHECKINOUT.DefaultOut, CHECKINOUT.DefaultBreckIn, 
   CHECKINOUT.DefaultBreakOut, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, USERINFO.TITLE
FROM           
   (CHECKINOUT 
    INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID)
WHERE 
   (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME >= ?) 
   AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME <= ?) 
   AND (CHECKINOUT.USERID = ? OR ? = - 1) 
   AND (CHECKINOUT.DefaultIn <=  CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME OR
        CHECKINOUT.DefaultOut >= CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME )
```

What's the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Format function in your query, example:

```
Format([datetime column],'dd-mm-yyyy @ hh:nn:ss AM/PM')
```

and in your SQL:

```
SELECT Format([CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME],'dd-mm-yyyy @ hh:nn:ss AM/PM') AS DT_CHECKTIME ...
```